# acts_as_nested_set *** ArgumentError Exception: Unknown key: :order

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, upgrade

Upgrading rails3.2.21 to 4.1.9 and in a class i have use acts_as_nested_set and there is a has_many relation between two class 
 see below **code**

```
class Area < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_nested_set
    has_many :plans
end

class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :area
end
```

when i am try to **calculate**

```
p = Plan.first

p.area
```

through an **error on terminal** like-

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Unknown key: :order. Valid keys are: :class_name, :class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :table_name, :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove, :extend, :primary_key, :dependent, :as, :through, :source, :source_type, :inverse_of, :counter_cache, :join_table):
```

how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This  issue was because i have use the gem

gem 'awesome_nested_set', '~> 2.1.6'

And now i have update the gem file and add gem

gem "awesome_nested_set", '~> 3.0.0.rc.3'

Issue is fixed now

Comment: I have 3.1.3 and still get the issue :(